# Cloudfoundry restage terminal signals

Tags: cloud-foundry

Currently I have a micro service running in `cloud foundry`. I am trapping `sigterm` and `sighup`.  I’m trying to verify which signal is sent when a `cf restage` is performed. I’ve seen the terminal signals for a lot of other commands except for this one in the docs. I would appreciate if somebody can point me to any documentation or just knowledge on the signal sent to the operating system on a cf restage. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The signal that you are sent shouldn't differ between `cf` actions (i.e. stop, restart, restage, or even if your app is restarted due to foundation maintenance) it should always get a SIGTERM, ten seconds to nicely shutdown, followed by a SIGKILL.

https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-6/devguide/deploy-apps/app-lifecycle.html#shutdown

I did a little test on Pivotal Web Service to confirm when using `cf restage`, where I catch and log when SIGTERM is sent. You can see right in the middle where the SIGTERM is caught by the app. It's just a little harder to see in this case because you also have the staging logs coming through at the same time.

Hope that helps!

```
   2019-08-25T22:02:02.90-0400 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 65a71ce1-e630-4765-8f60-adebfa730268 stopping instance a91e593b-d9b6-42aa-7021-b8cd
   2019-08-25T22:02:02.98-0400 [API/9] OUT Creating build for app with guid f58e6aae-783d-4a28-bd30-54c20d314ef4
   2019-08-25T22:02:03.87-0400 [STG/0] OUT Downloading binary_buildpack...
   2019-08-25T22:02:03.91-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT running
   2019-08-25T22:02:03.94-0400 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded binary_buildpack
   2019-08-25T22:02:03.94-0400 [STG/0] OUT Cell 9aa90abe-6a8f-4485-90d1-71da907de9a3 creating container for instance 4cd508ee-3ce3-4e61-a9b7-5a997ca5583e
   2019-08-25T22:02:05.36-0400 [STG/0] OUT Cell 9aa90abe-6a8f-4485-90d1-71da907de9a3 successfully created container for instance 4cd508ee-3ce3-4e61-a9b7-5a997ca5583e
   2019-08-25T22:02:05.72-0400 [STG/0] OUT Downloading app package...
   2019-08-25T22:02:05.72-0400 [STG/0] OUT Downloading build artifacts cache...
   2019-08-25T22:02:05.77-0400 [STG/0] ERR Downloading build artifacts cache failed
   2019-08-25T22:02:05.92-0400 [STG/0] OUT Downloaded app package (651.6K)
   2019-08-25T22:02:06.57-0400 [STG/0] OUT -----> Binary Buildpack version 1.0.33
   2019-08-25T22:02:06.83-0400 [STG/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2019-08-25T22:02:06.83-0400 [STG/0] OUT Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
   2019-08-25T22:02:06.83-0400 [STG/0] OUT Uploading droplet...
   2019-08-25T22:02:06.83-0400 [STG/0] OUT Uploading build artifacts cache...
   2019-08-25T22:02:06.97-0400 [STG/0] OUT Uploaded build artifacts cache (215B)
   2019-08-25T22:02:07.02-0400 [API/2] OUT Creating droplet for app with guid f58e6aae-783d-4a28-bd30-54c20d314ef4
   2019-08-25T22:02:08.12-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT SIGTERM caught, exiting
   2019-08-25T22:02:08.13-0400 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2019-08-25T22:02:08.20-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 134
   2019-08-25T22:02:08.28-0400 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 65a71ce1-e630-4765-8f60-adebfa730268 destroying container for instance a91e593b-d9b6-42aa-7021-b8cd
   2019-08-25T22:02:08.91-0400 [PROXY/0] OUT Exit status 137
   2019-08-25T22:02:09.16-0400 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 65a71ce1-e630-4765-8f60-adebfa730268 successfully destroyed container for instance a91e593b-d9b6-42aa-7021-b8cd
   2019-08-25T22:02:10.07-0400 [STG/0] OUT Uploaded droplet (653.1K)
   2019-08-25T22:02:10.07-0400 [STG/0] OUT Uploading complete
   2019-08-25T22:02:11.24-0400 [STG/0] OUT Cell 9aa90abe-6a8f-4485-90d1-71da907de9a3 stopping instance 4cd508ee-3ce3-4e61-a9b7-5a997ca5583e
   2019-08-25T22:02:11.24-0400 [STG/0] OUT Cell 9aa90abe-6a8f-4485-90d1-71da907de9a3 destroying container for instance 4cd508ee-3ce3-4e61-a9b7-5a997ca5583e
   2019-08-25T22:02:11.68-0400 [CELL/0] OUT Cell e9fa9dcc-6c6e-4cd4-97cd-5781aa4c64e6 creating container for instance f2bc9aaa-64cf-4331-53b5-bd5f
   2019-08-25T22:02:11.95-0400 [STG/0] OUT Cell 9aa90abe-6a8f-4485-90d1-71da907de9a3 successfully destroyed container for instance 4cd508ee-3ce3-4e61-a9b7-5a997ca5583e
   2019-08-25T22:02:13.28-0400 [CELL/0] OUT Cell e9fa9dcc-6c6e-4cd4-97cd-5781aa4c64e6 successfully created container for instance f2bc9aaa-64cf-4331-53b5-bd5f
   2019-08-25T22:02:14.43-0400 [CELL/0] OUT Downloading droplet...
   2019-08-25T22:02:14.78-0400 [CELL/0] OUT Downloaded droplet (653.1K)
   2019-08-25T22:02:16.07-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT running
```